# Japanese Text not showing correctly

Tags: html, css, encoding

Currently I am working on a website which has some text in Japanese Language. All the texts are showing weird in all browser. The website has "charset" of "Shift_JIS". I have recoded the website with some new code as it was coded 10 years ago with some table like email template.

Here is the Head part of the site

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
<title>コミックで英語を学ぶ,,漫画で学ぶ英語:, ESL, EFL, TOEFL, FCE, TOIEC, IELTS</title>
```

All the texts are looking like this 
[image]
Here is all the code I have used in the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
<title>コミックで英語を学ぶ,,漫画で学ぶ英語:, ESL, EFL, TOEFL, FCE, TOIEC, IELTS</title>


<script language="JavaScript">
<!--HPB_SCRIPT_ROV_50
//
// Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
// 83H7391, 42L1820
// (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1995, 1999  All Rights Reserved.
//
// Version: 5.0.1
//

// HpbImgPreload: 画像のプリロードを行ないます
//
function HpbImgPreload()
{
  var appVer=parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
  var isNC=(document.layers && (appVer >= 4)); // Netscape Navigator 4.0 or later
  var isIE=(document.all    && (appVer >= 4)); // Internet Explorer  4.0 or later
  if (isNC || isIE)
  {
    if (document.images)
    {
      var imgName = HpbImgPreload.arguments[0];
      var cnt;
      swImg[imgName] = new Array;
      for (cnt = 1; cnt < HpbImgPreload.arguments.length; cnt++)
      {
        swImg[imgName][HpbImgPreload.arguments[cnt]] = new Image();
        swImg[imgName][HpbImgPreload.arguments[cnt]].src = HpbImgPreload.arguments[cnt];
      }
    }
  }
}
// HpbImgFind: Imageオブジェクトを探します
//
function HpbImgFind(doc, imgName)
{
  for (var i=0; i < doc.layers.length; i++)
  {
    var img = doc.layers[i].document.images[imgName];
    if (!img) img = HpbImgFind(doc.layers[i], imgName);
    if (img) return img;
  }
  return null;
}
// HpbImgSwap: 画像を入れ換えます
//
function HpbImgSwap(imgName, imgSrc)
{
  var appVer=parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
  var isNC=(document.layers && (appVer >= 4)); // Netscape Navigator 4.0 or later
  var isIE=(document.all    && (appVer >= 4)); // Internet Explorer  4.0 or later
  if (isNC || isIE)
  {
    if (document.images)
    {
      var img = document.images[imgName];
      if (!img) img = HpbImgFind(document, imgName);
      if (img) img.src = imgSrc;
    }
  }
}
var swImg; swImg=new Array;
//-->
</script><script language="JavaScript">
<!--
HPB_SCRIPT_PLD_50
HpbImgPreload('_HPB_ROLLOVER3', 'image/english02.gif', 'image/english01.gif');
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
TD {
    font-size : 12px;
}
-->
</style>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="header row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><img src="banners/banner-cfangollll-flyguy600-105.png"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="middle row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="background:#fff">
    <div class="top_sec_mid row">
      <div class="top_text">
        <h1 align="center"><br>
          コミックデ英語学ぶ</h1>
        <h1 align="center">世界コッミクで国際的なビジネス言語を勉強。</h1>
        <h5 align="center"><br>
          <b>Language Learning thru World Comics</b> </h5>
      </div>
      <!--top_text ends-->
      <div class="top_txt2"> 英語を学ぶ人、そして教える人を対象とした、プリントOK、フォトフリーのお手
        軽レッスン。難易度は中レベルで、初級編・中級編・上級編の3段階に別れてい
        る。まずは下のタイトルをクリックしてみよう。 </div>
      <div class="pdf">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="list_left  col-md-9 col-sm-9"><img src="images/flag-icon_us.png" width="27" height="17">幻視少女（作：リー・ケネディ）</div>
            <div class="list_right col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="image/p.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="pdf version">コミック</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list_left  col-md-9  col-sm-9"><img src="images/flag-icon_Flag_of_England.png" width="27" height="17"> ルッキング（作：キャスパー・ウィリアムス）</div>
            <div class="list_right  col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="image/p.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="pdf version">コミック</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list_left col-md-9  col-sm-9"><img src="images/flag-icon_icon-denmark.png" width="27" height="17"> 冷や汗タラタラ（作：オーレ・コモル</div>
            <div class="list_right  col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="image/p.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="pdf version">コミック</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list_left col-md-9  col-sm-9"><img src="images/flag-icon_dutch.png" width="27" height="17"> ピート（作：マイケ・ハーチェス）</div>
            <div class="list_right  col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="image/p.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="pdf version"><a href="maahar22/index.html">コミック</a></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list_left col-md-9  col-sm-9"><img src="images/flag-icon_germany-flag-icon.png" width="27" height="17"> 悪魔主義死神カルト（作：ウルリッチ・メイジン）</div>
            <div class="list_right  col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="image/p.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="pdf version">コミック</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list_left col-md-9  col-sm-9"><img src="images/flag-icon_Serbia Yugoslavia.png" width="27" height="17"> 夢見るセルビア人（作：アレクサンダー・ゾグラフ）</div>
            <div class="list_right   col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="image/p.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="pdf version"><a href="alezog/index.html" target="_blank">コミック</a></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--top_sec_mid-->

    <div class="mid_box_1">
      <div class="mid_box1_img"><img src="alezog/serdre_02.gif" width="465" height="281"></div>
      <div align="center" class="mid_box1_txt"> <strong>aleksandar zograf </strong><br>
        （作：アレクサンダー・ゾグラフ）<br>
        夢見るセルビア人 </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_1 ends-->

    <div class="mid_box_2">
      <div class="mid_box2_img"><img src="olecom/olecomTOP.gif" width="431" height="306" alt=""></div>
      <div align="center" class="mid_box2_txt"> <strong>ole comoll</strong><br>
        I was hopelessly in love. I couldn't sleep, but lay think of her....Every day I came to see her, but all I dared to say to her was: "The usual please." It went on for some weeks until: "And here?" </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_2 ends-->

    <div class="mid_box_3">
      <div class="mid_box3_img"><img src="caswil/look0203.gif" width="222" height="258" alt=""></div>
      <div align="center " class="mid_box3_txt"> <strong>　caspar williams</strong><br>
        カスパーウィリアムズは、毎日の生活が何のためにあるのかということに全く確新が待ってない人々のために神経質な物語シリーズを書いている。Suburban Nightmare シリーズの中の LOOKING（ルキングか見ている）でもどちらかといえばふつうの状況にあるふつうの男が 神経質になっていく。Mr. Williams は<small><font face="ＭＳ ゴシック" lang="JA">ブ</font></small>ライトンで植物だけを友にひとりで住んでいる。 <strong>Click <a href="clp01.html">here </a>for details on how to get your 6 bilingual comics and free sample Language Learning thru Comics Lesson</strong> </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_3 ends-->

    <div class="mid_box_4">
      <div class="mid_box4_img"><img src="leeken22/02t_r2_c2_f2.gif" width="205" height="228" alt=""></div>
      <div align="center " class="mid_box4_txt">
        <p><strong>lee kennedy</strong><br>
          幻視少女（作：リー・ケネディ</p>
        <p><strong>Click <a href="clp01.html">here </a>for details on how to get your 6 bilingual comics and free sample Language Learning thru Comics Lesson</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_4 ends-->

    <div class="mid_box_5">
      <div class="mid_box5_img"><img src="maahar22/maaful4.gif" width="241" height="332" alt=""></div>
      <div align="center mid_box5_txt" class="mid_box5_txt"> <strong>maaike hartjes</strong><br>
        この小さな物語は私の友人ピートについて,彼はいいやつですが、巨大な浮気者です。 <strong>Click <a href="clp01.html">here </a>for details on how to get your 6 bilingual comics and free sample Language Learning thru Comics Lesson</strong> </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_5 ends-->

    <div class="mid_box_6">
      <div class="mid_box6_img"><img src="ulrmag/ulrTOP.gif" width="425" height="367"></div>
      <div align="center mid_box6_txt" class="mid_box6_txt">
        <p>ulrich magin</p>
        <p><strong>Click <a href="clp01.html">here </a>for details on how to get your 6 bilingual comics and free sample Language Learning thru Comics Lesson</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_6 ends-->

    <div class="mid_box_7">
      <div class="mid_box7_img1 col-md-6"><img src="images/holocomics-template-FLATSURFACEVIEWnoLAYERS400traN.png" width="316" height="192"></div>
      <div class="mid_box7_img2 col-md-6">
        <div class="box7_txt">
          <h5>xxxxxxxxxxxxx<a href="clp01.html">xxxxx</a></h5>
          <h6>Click <a href="clp01.html">here </a>for details on how to get your 6 bilingual comics and free sample Language Learning thru Comics Lesson</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--mid_box_7 ends-->

    <div class="bottom_blue row">
      <div class="mid_box_8">
        <div align="center" class="mid_box8_txt">
          <p align="left">６部バイリンガルの漫画（アメリカ、ドイツ、オランダ、デンマーク、セルビア,英国から１つずつ、が無料で付いてきます。それぞれ単語と文法練習が付いたレッスンで物語を完全に理解し、イギリスとアメリカ英語で考え、話せるようになります。 </p>
          <h6 align="left">What you get for free are 6 bilingual comics (one each from America,　Serbia, Holland, Germany, Denmark and  England). Each includes a complete lesson that will ensure that you know the story as well as  how to think and talk about it in English.　What are you waiting for?</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="mid_box8_img1"><img src="images/serdre-bilinguallastPage.png" width="600" height="354"></div>
      </div>

      <!--mid_box_8 ends-->

      <div class="mid_box_9">
        <table width="60%" border="2">
          <tr>
            <th height="372" bgcolor="#0066FF" scope="col"><h6 align="left">Maximizeyour your learning and memorization potential with three modes.　Experience these comics and lessons thru your three main senses, </h6>
              <h1 align="center">Listen See Feel</h1>
              <p align="center">(auditory, visual and kinethetic) </p>
              <p align="center">then </p>
              <h1 align="center">Think and Create</h1>
              <h6 align="left">(auditory, visual and kinethetic) </h6>
              <table width="88%" border="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <th height="42" scope="col"><img src="images/icon-movie2.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-text.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-voice.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-hear-2.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-comic40.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-slideshow.png" width="40" height="40"></th>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="88%" border="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <th height="42" scope="col"><img src="images/image-blank-transparent40b.png" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/image-blank-transparent40b.png" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-watch2.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/icon-do.jpg" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/image-blank-transparent40b.png" width="40" height="40"></th>
                  <th scope="col"><img src="images/image-blank-transparent40b.png" width="40" height="40"></th>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <p align="left">Depending on what kind of learner you are (auditory, visual or kinesthetic),  I believe  it is best to 1) listen<img src="images/icon-hear-2.jpg" width="40" height="40">, 2)see <img src="images/icon-watch2.jpg" width="36" height="36"> and feel <img src="images/icon-do.jpg" width="40" height="40"> the comic and finally, 3) involve yourself in Creative Thinkingcheck out the translated version <img src="images/Flag_of_Japan_27.png" width="27" height="17"> <img src="images/icon-plus20.jpg" width="20" height="20"> <img src="images/flag-icon_british-flag.png" width="27" height="17">. You should then be ready for the lesson.</p>
              <h6 align="center">All the audio is inEnglish in accents from various countries. </h6></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <!--mid_box9-->

      <div class="mid_box_10">
        <table width="60%" border="2">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><div align="center">
                <table width="60%" border="2">
                  <tr>
                    <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="col"><div align="center">
                        <p><img src="images/wordshoot.gif" alt="Language Learning Game " width="228" height="22"><br>
                        </p>
                      </div></th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <p><img src="images/worshoot-scrnsht.jpg" alt="Wordshoot: Language Learning Game" width="232" height="184"></p>
              </div></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <!--mid_box10-->

      <div class="mid_box_11">
        <h2 align="center" >（語学学習シューティング・ゲーム：TOIEC, TOEFL, IELTS, ケンブリッジ英検対策用）
          100以上の問題＆回答を収録。<br>
          <br>
          <strong>PC版：ここをクリック！　MAC版：ここをクリック！ </strong></h2>
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
          <tr valign="top">
            <td ><p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
              <p align="center" style="color:#fff;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="１"><b>Language 
                Learning shoot 'em up for learners of TOIEC, TOEFL, IELTS et) </b></font></p>
              <h6 align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333333">A horde of illiterate, savage, grammatically-challenged and linguistically-dysfunctional 
                mutant aliens from a far off planet in an alternative dimension 
                want you for breakfast. Prevent this from happening by downloading this somewhat retro but still fun game.</font> <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#333333">Yummmy!</font></h6></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--mid_box11-->

      <div class="mid_box_12">
        <table width="78%" border="2">
          <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" scope="col"><div align="left">
                <h2 style="color:#000">上のコミック好きだったら、きっと、あなたがこの南蛮画（ナンバンガ）２３ヶ国、６０
                  以上の漫画家の作品集大好きです。。。。<br>
                </h2>
                <h5 align="center" style="color:#000">If you like the comics above you'll love the works on the Nambanga Collection .</h5>
                <div align="center">
                  <table width="80%" border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <th bgcolor="#3E8FD1" scope="col"><a href="bios/creBiosFinalJ.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image10','','images/nambangaBCK.jpg',1)"><img src="images/nambangaFRONT.jpg" alt="xxxxxx" width="404" height="600" id="Image10"></a></th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <h2 align="left" style="color:#000"><a href="bios/creBiosFinalJ.html">ここ</a>はアーティストやクリエイターのインクです（略歴も読めます！！）</h2>
                  <h5 align="center" style="color:#000"><a href="bios/creBiosFinalJ.html">here</a> is a link to a list of the artists and creators and short bios. </h5>
                  <h2 align="center" style="color:#000">★ ★ ★  今だけ999円 ★ ★ ★</h2>
                  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
                  <h2 align="center" style="color:#000">75%割引きです</h2>
                  <p align="center" style="color:#000">★ ★ ★　はいそうです　★ ★ ★</p>
                  <h2 align="center" style="color:#000">75%オフ</h2>
                  <h6 align="center" style="color:#000">Now only 750 yen (that's a 75% discount)</h6>
                  <p align="center"><img src="images/warning.png" width="60" height="60"></p>
                  <h2 align="center" style="color:#000">成人向けの漫画</h2>
                  <h2 align="left" style="color:#000">いくつかの物語を子どもたちにとって不適切であると考えていますよ。</h2>
                  <h5 align="left" style="color:#000">Some stories are suitable for a mature audience only!!!</h5>
                  <p align="center"><img src="images/banner-holoM-signmeUP-englishJP.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor..."></p>
                </div>
                <div align="center"></div>
              </div>
              <div align="center">
                <table width="58%" border="2">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><div align="left">
                        <h2 style="color:#000">ホロミーム言語暗記システムは、英語学習が効率的になるだけでなく、スペイン語でも中国語でもフランス語でもどんな言語でもあなたが学びたい学習に役立ちます。</h2>
                        <h5 align="center"><img src="images/logo_header.jpg" width="289" height="86"></h5>
                        <h5 align="center">The Holo-MeME Language Memorization System will help you to learn not  only ENGLISH faster and<br>
                          more efficiently but also Spanish, French, Chinese. In fact, whatever language you want to learn.<br>
                        </h5>
                      </div></th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--mid_box12-->

      <div class="mid_box_13"> <a href="bios/creBiosFinalJ.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image25','','banners/banner_nambanga-titlewithdilcar728b-60-20.jpg',1)"><img src="banners/banner_nambanga-titlewithdilcar600only-60-20.jpg" width="600" height="74" id="Image25"></a> </div>
      <!--mid_box13--> 

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer row">
  <p><img src="banners/banner-cfangollll-flyguyblack600-105.png" width="600" height="105">
    <center>
      <iframe src="footer.html"  frameBorder="0" width="610" height="100"></iframe>
    </center>
  </p>
</div>
<style>



</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: The code you posted seems correct, you probably already managed to convert it correctly to unicode and you just need to remove the meta charset tag, or change it to UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, apparently, is that the encoding which you have declared (Shift_JIS) no longer matches the actual encoding used (probably UTF-8), and so the browser renders garbage. Either that, or your browser doesn't recognize the Shift_JIS encoding.

What may have happened is that when you edited the source, your text editor re-wrote the text in its preferred encoding, which differed from Shift_JIS. It's not possible to tell which encoding your current source file is in based on the code you posted; we'd need to have the raw file.

Another possibility is that your source is, in fact, encoded in Shift_JIS correctly, but your server is serving the page with a mis-matched `Content-Type` header which is overriding the `<meta>` tag.

In any case, I would recommend switching things entirely to UTF-8 where possible.

Try changing the declared charset of your page to UTF-8 (maybe add the modern `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag while you're at it). If that doesn't work, try these steps:

- Convert the original source to UTF-8

  - Open the original source in your editor
  - Ensure that the text displays properly in the editor (means the editor recognizes the encoding)
  - Use the editor's settings to re-save as UTF-8
- Change the declared encoding to UTF-8
- Apply your changes

Comment: first added <meta charset="utf-8"> in the head tag. then saved the file with UTF-8 encoding.